# Calculate force of a vertically falling object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces

The force of Earth's gravity on the weight of a human being with a mass of 70 kg is approximately 686 N.

What would be the force of Earth's gravity if this human would jump down from a 1 meter height?

Comment: Why do you think the force of gravity would change because of a 1m jump?

Comment: What I am trying to ask here is the following. If a person would step on a scale he would weight 70kg, if he jumps on a scale, the scale would show a bigger number than 70kg for a small period of time. So what happens here?

Comment: A scale does not measure the "force of gravity", it measures just force. This is only the force of gravity alone if you're standing still on it.

Comment: right, that makes sense. a scale measure weight. why the weight is different if a person jumps on it?

Answer (score 2):

> What I am trying to ask here is the following. If a 70 kg person would step
>   on a scale he would weigh 680 N, if he jumps on a scale, the scale
>   would show a bigger number than 680 N for a small period of time. So
>   what happens here?

In response to your above follow up comment that clarified your original question, the scale will show a bigger number because it is not giving you just the weight of the person, but rather the much larger impact force on the scale due to the kinetic energy the person acquired during the jump. You can estimate the average impact force by applying the work energy theorem which states that the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy, or in this case

$$F_{ave}d=\frac{mv^2}{2}$$

Where $F_{ave}$ is the average impact force, $d$ is the stopping distance of the center of mass of the person, $m$ is the mass and $v$ is the velocity of the person on impact. You can see from the equation that the shorter the stopping distance, the greater the average impact force, and vice-versa.

You can calculate $v$ because the kinetic energy will equal the loss in potential energy of the center of mass for the 1 meter jump.

The worst case for $d$ would be if the person landed standing straight up, without bending the knees, since $d$ would only be the small compression of the scale. The impact is lessened considerably if the person bends the knees while bringing him/her self to a stop which increases the stopping distance.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When just standing on the scale, it is an equilibrium situation and W - N1 = 0 where W is the weight of the person and N1 is the upward force of the scale on the person (which is what the scale is reading). I'm taking the downward direction as positive.

If the person jumps on the scale, when contact is made he starts decelerating or accelerating in the upward direction. At some time during this process, we have

W - N2 = -(W/g)a

where W/g is the person's mass and a (a positive number ) is the upward acceleration at that instant.

Thus, N2 = W + (W/g)a

and N2 > N1 at that instant.